# Magento 2 Uncaught TypeError Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-express, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p1

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined
    at UiClass.continueToPayPal (paypal-express-abstract.js:80)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (knockout.js:4245)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5232)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4884)
```

[image]

when I have click on the PayPal Express Checkout button page is not redirect and show me the error in the console any one idea why to show this error.

Comment: are you able to fix this issue ?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: yes, comment the done function than working this is a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed, i use One Step Checkout from BSS COMMERCE.
The file located in Bss/OneStepCheckout/view/frontend/web/js/action set-payment-information-extended.js problems with serviceUrl I removed it in the if and i removed the other control now it works.

```
   /**
     * Checkout for guest and registered customer.
     */
        if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
        serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/guest-carts/:cartId/set-payment-information', {
            cartId: quote.getQuoteId()
        });
        payload.email = quote.guestEmail;
    } else {
        serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/carts/mine/set-payment-information', {});
    }
```